# Is there a way to indicate a variable is being passed ByRef in VB?

Tags: vb.net, byref

Is there a way to indicate a variable is being passed ByRef in VB? I know in C# they have a `ref` keyword that must be present in both the function header and in the calling code. Does VB have an equivalent?

For example, my function looks like this

```
private function add_one(byRef value)as Boolean
```

the calling code would look like this

```
increment_was_successful = add_one(ByRef value)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you simply use `ByRef` instead of `ByVal` in the method, and then just pass the variable in with no keywords - like `increment_was_successful = add_one(value)`.

Comment: @Tim yeah you are right, you dont need the keyword when calling the method but I was hoping you could indicate it. It increases readability when glancing over code. maybe readability isn't the proper term, I would just rather see it explicitly so there is no confusion

Comment: You can stop looking, no equivalent syntax exists.  It had some unrelated usage back in the VB6 days, used to generate a pointer value, not otherwise carried forward into VB.NET

Comment: Thanks Hans, I figured this was the case

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out VB simply doesn't support this form.

```
increment_was_successful = add_one(ByRef value)
```

You are left calling the function without any indicator that it is being passed byref

```
increment_was_successful = add_one(value)
```

Comment: VB.Net does support `ByRef`. It has to, since the rest of the .Net family does and the CLR does.

Comment: @StarPilot do you find my new solution acceptable? I know that .net supports what are basically pointers, i was just looking for a specific format. The way a c#.net program would use the `out` parameter to emulate a pointer, something like this `increment_was_successful = add_one(out value)`

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my confusing comment...

ByRef and ByVal are used in the definition of the parameters of a sub or function - not on the call.

Here is some code the sort of follows the OP question:

```
Dim orgVal As Integer = 1

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim increment_was_successful As Boolean
    increment_was_successful = add_one(orgVal)
    MsgBox(increment_was_successful & " - " & orgVal)
End Sub

Private Function add_one(ByRef value As Integer) As Boolean
    Const limit As Integer = 3
    If value <= limit - 1 Then
        value += 1
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Note the ByRef in the Function definition. If you change ByRef to ByVal you will see the orgVal never changes a 'value' is local to add_one and not a pointer (ByRef) to orgVal.